# A transformation of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose I have a convergent infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n = S_0$ and $0 < S_0 < 1$.  Write $s_n$ for the $n$-th partial sum. ($s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k a_k$) Now consider the new series $$S_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left ( \prod_{k = 1}^n s_k \right)$$ where we understand the empty product to be 1 (so that this is the first term.)  This new series converges by the ratio test.

Can anything be said about its value? For example, if we always have $0 < S_1 < 1$, we could iterate the transformation to get a sequence of values $S_0, S_1, S_2, \dots$.  Can anything be said about this sequence?  I guess I'm wondering if anyone has seen this type of thing before (maybe it has a name?)

Comment: Some motivation would be helpful.  This is a strange construction.

Comment: Yes, this is rather peculiar. My reading of the literature of series transformation has never encountered multiplying together partial sums.

Comment: I am a bit lazy to calculate : look at what happens with $a_k=(1/2)^k$, and more generally $a_k=(1/p)^k$ can you calculate the $S_i$